# How can I subtract a scalar from every element in one axis of an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to normalize the background of an image read in with `imread()` which produces a NxMx3 ndarray.

To do this I need to subtract the NxMx0 axis from 255, the NxMx1 axis from 250, and the NxMx2 axis from 225.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply subtract your image from an array of the R, G, and B values and `numpy` will [implicitly broadcast them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html). This works since the last dimension of `image` matches the dimension of your array.

```
import numpy as np

# Some test data
image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (3,3,3))

#   array([[[218,  51, 105],
#           [227,  34,  20],
#           [ 68,  65,  41]],
#
#          [[ 43, 171, 110],
#           [166, 253, 191],
#           [ 86,  26,  28]],
#
#          [[167, 117, 167],
#           [ 96,  82,  21],
#           [ 45, 232, 127]]])

result = [255, 250, 225] - image

#   array([[[ 37, 199, 120],
#           [ 28, 216, 205],
#           [187, 185, 184]],
#
#          [[212,  79, 115],
#           [ 89,  -3,  34],
#           [169, 224, 197]],
# 
#          [[ 88, 133,  58],
#           [159, 168, 204],
#           [210,  18,  98]]])
```